# Populate multiple comboboxes with the same values

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have 8 comboboxes on my form that will all hold the same values - Yes and No.

Is there a quicker way than having to do combox1.items.add("Yes") etc?

I have the following but I cant seem to find anything to do with adding the items.

```
    Dim cmb As Control
    For Each cmb In Panel1.Controls
        If TypeOf cmb Is ComboBox Then
'cmb. isnt beinging anything up for adding items?
        End If
Next
```

Cheers

Comment: `cmb` is still a `Control` in that case; you'd need `DirectCast(cmb, ComboBox).Items.Add`. But use @TimSchmelter's solution instead, and make sure not to declare `cmb` in advance in that case :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.OfType`:

```
For Each cmb In Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)()
    cmb.Items.Add("Yes")
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `DataSource` containing `{Yes,No}` values, for example as a `List` and then just do this:

```
For Each cmb In Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)()
  cmb.DataSource = myYesNoDataSource
Next
```

Later if you need to accept `Y` and `N` in place of `Yes` and `No`, you can convert to `Dictionary` and set `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` accordingly. Plus your list of available values is only initialized once. So your solution becomes flexible.

Answer (score 0):

This Code will be useful, if you didnt use panel.
If you have 5 comboboxes give count 1 to 5 and name of those comboboxes like ComboBox1, ComboBox2, comboBox3 etc.

```
For count = 1 To 5
Dim combobox = DirectCast(Me.Controls("ComboBox" & n & ""), ComboBox)
combobox.Items.Add("Ok")
Next
```

Hope this code also helps you.